# "Guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr" - why neue and not neuen?

Tags: adjective-ending

"Ich wünsche dir einen guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr" is a nice wish for New Year. But I'm confused - why it's not "ins neuen Jahr"? My reasoning is: "Ich" is Subjekt, "einen guten Rutsch" is Akkusativobjekt, "ins neue Jahr" must be Dativobjekt. Adjective stands before noun and therefore must be declined, and we have definite article in front (in + das = ins) so adjective ending must be -en (like in "Ich helfe einem kleinen Kind"). So, why is "ins neue Jahr" and not "ins neuen Jahr"?

Comment: The construction you're thinking of would be “Guten Rutsch **im** neuen Jahr”, which would be gramatically correct but missing the point of the phrase.

Comment: The problem with the reasoning is that there can be more than one noun of any case in a sentence. I would call *das neue Jahr* a "prepositional object" because it's case is governed by a preposition, not the verb. Even without prepositions this reasoning would not work: *Ich bin der Arzt.* (Two nouns in nominative) *Ich treffe dich nächstes Jahr.* (Two nouns in accusitive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to distinguish (at least) two cases with "in". If you're talking about an action *inside* something, the *location* of the action, you need the dative:

> Er rutscht in der Küche aus.

> He slips in the kitchen (inside the kitchen).

If you're talking about an action *into* something, the *direction* of the action, you need the accusative:

> Er rutscht in die Küche hinein.

> He slips / slides into the kitchen.

In your example sentence, you're wishing "a good slide into the new year". Therefore, you need the accusative:

> Ich wünsche Dir einen guten Rutsch in das neue Jahr hinein.

> Ich wünsche Dir einen guten Rutsch in das neue Jahr.

> Ich wünsche Dir einen guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr.