# Why is "Ich kaufe in einem guten Geschäft ein" and "Ich fahre in ein schickes Hotel"?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammar-identification

> Ich kaufe in einem guten Geschäft ein

> Ich fahre in ein schickes Hotel

Both phrases have neutral nouns, use "in" as preposition, but for Geschäft the dativ is used and for Hotel the Akk is used. Why?

Comment: The dative is often used to denote _location_, while the accusative is often used to denote _direction_. There have been multiple questions about this topic, see for example [this similar question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61554/guten-rutsch-ins-neue-jahr-why-neue-and-not-neuen/61555#61555).

Comment: Adding to what @HenningKockerbeck said: the question you'd use to ask for the object are different in both cases (at least in German): **Where** (wo) vs. **Whither** (wohin)? (Yes, it's archaic, but it's a useful distinction, and needed in German.)

Comment: @Ingmar You would be astonished how useless *asking for the case* (while very useful for native speakers) is to non-natives.

Comment: Well, that's all I got in this case. It's true, I have no background in teaching DAF (Deutsch als Fremdsprache) …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Verben sind "einkaufen" und "fahren". "Einkaufen" hat keine Richtung: Du musst *in dem Geschäft* sein um einkaufen zu können, deshalb Dativ. "Fahren" hat eine Richtung: Die Richtung ist das Hotel.

(Es gibt Ausnahmen: Ich fahre drei Runden auf dem Nürburgring. Hier findet das Fahren in einem (ziemlich großen) Platz statt. Der Nürburgring ist nicht das Ziel. )